# How to replace css class back ground image

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Im using Mvc and jquery, i would like to know how can I get an image to display.

I have

```
<img src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Dashboard")" id="images" alt="image description" width="100" height="72" />
```

and inside my scrip tags I have

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        getTheme();
        var imageSource = $('#images');
        var newimg = $('.logo');
        newimg.css({'background-image', 'Url('+imageSource+')'});
    </script>
```

I want this to be the source: 

The image is just not showing can you help me.

Comment: When you do imageSource you're getting the `object` returned to you, so when you're attempting to inject `imageSource` as the `background-image url`, it's trying to use an object. You need to get the `src attribute` of the `imageSource object`. This is achieved by doing something like - `imageSource = imageSource.attr('src')`. Insert then inbetween `var imageSource` and `var newimg` - this will give you the desired effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
var imageSource = $('#images');
```

to

```
var imageSource = $('#images').attr("src");
```

to get the actual path and not the DOM-Element.

Answer (score 2):

i think this may help you:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        getTheme();
        var imageSource = $('#images').attr('src');
        var newimg = $('.logo');
        newimg.css({'background-image', 'Url('+imageSource+')'});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your imageSource variable. I guess you need to take the src attribute of the #images element if it is a image tag. Overall i think the only thing not working is the imageSource value. More info on this can help resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe ?

```
newimg.attr('src', imageSource.attr('src'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#bg_image').removeClass('.logo').addClass('#images');
```

And the css code:

```
.logo{background-image:url(image1.png);}
#image{background-image:url(image2.png);}
```